# Why doesn't the hover state of the parent change the child's line-height, even with "!important"?

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the parent div, despite setting `line-height: 3em !important", the child`line-height` never changes.

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/80o088ue/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 1.25em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    height: 2.125em;
    width: 2.125em;
    float: left;
    border: solid 3px #143a58;
    background-color: #57b7e2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2.125em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2.125em;
    border-radius: 2.125em;
    overflow: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container:hover
{
    width: 2.25em;
    height: 2.25em;
    margin-top: 1.1875em;
    margin-left: .9375em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    line-height: 3em !important;
}

.container .text
{
    position: relative;
    font-family: LatoRegular, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2.833em;
    color: #143a58;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you trying to change the line-height of the text class?

Comment: because you override the default parent  line-height which is supposed to be inherited by ".text" with this "line-height: 2.833em;".. also..."line-height: 3em !important" only applies to the parent since you explicity added the rule mentioned for line-height for the child.

Comment: By default line-height is set to inherit (inherit the line-height from its parent element). However you are setting it to 2.833em so it is no longer set to inherit it from its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container:hover > .text{
  // other css code
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

By using the  > selector, your CSS rule should alter the line-height of the .text child element when you hover the parent .container element, instead of the line-height of .container itself.

Answer (score 0):

Beacause `.text` already has `line-height: 2.833em;` in the class properties, it overrides the `line-height` that comes from the parent through the cascade. To fix that, just changed the`line-height` of `.text` on hover ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/80o088ue/1/)):

```
.container:hover .text {
  line-height: 3em;
}
```